# Argument of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha$ a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|\alpha'| = 1$. When we construct the argument of $\alpha'$ we consider the integral of the curvature and every works fine. But, why we can not simply define
$$
\theta(t) = \arccos(\alpha'(t)\cdot e_1)?
$$
Is it about differentiability?

Comment: No. What is the range (codomain)of the arccos function?

Comment: The domain is $[-1,1]$ and the codomain is $[-\pi,\pi]$ (when it is extended simetrically)

Comment: Huh? No. The codomain is $[0,\pi]$. Your definition does not work on a circle, let alone on a curve that winds around many times.